# Opening programs from a simple spot

Tags: python, beginner, osx

This is a simple program that opens programs from a simple spot:

```
import random
import webbrowser
import os
import yagmail
#importing all module ^^

greetings = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!','hey']
random_greeting = random.choice(greetings)

maps = ['maps', 'open google maps', 'open maps', 'please open google maps']

google = ['google', 'open google', 'please open google']

mail = ['mail', 'open mail', 'open google mail', 'please open google mail', 'gmail', 'open gmail', 'please open gmail']

safari = ['safari', 'open safari', 'please open safari']

calc = ['calc', 'calculator', 'open calc', 'open calculator', 'please open calc', 'please open calculator']

dict = ['dict', 'dictionary', 'open dict', 'open dictionary', 'please open dict', 'please open dictionary']

cal = ['cal', 'calendar', 'open cal', 'open calendar']

con = ['contacts', 'con', 'open contacts']

dash = ['dash', 'dashboard', 'open dashboard', 'open dash']

chess = ['chess', 'play chess', 'open chess']

face = ['facetime', 'face', 'open facetime']

band = ['garageband', 'garage band', 'band', 'garage', 'open band', 'open garage', 'open garage band', 'open garageband']

movie = ['imovie', 'open imovie']

ibooks = ['ibooks', 'open ibooks']

itunes = ['itunes', 'open itunes']

kindle = ['kindle', 'open kindle']

launch = ['launchpad', 'open launchpad']

amail = ['email', 'open email']

messages = ['messages', 'open messages']

notes = ['notes', 'open notes']

photos = ['photos', 'open photos']

reminders = ['reminders', 'open reminders']

stickies = ['stickies', 'open stickies']

textwrangler = ['textwrangler', 'text wrangler', 'open textwrangler', 'open text wrangler']

textedit = ['textedit', 'text edit', 'text', 'open text edit', 'open textedit']

xcode = ['xcode', 'open xcode']

emailing = ['send email', 'send']

question = ['How are you?','How are you doing?']
responses = ['Okay, How are you?',"I'm fine, How are you?"]
random_response = random.choice(responses)

#Defining everything ^^
while True:
    userInput = raw_input(">>> ").lower()
    if userInput in greetings:
        print(random_greeting)
    elif userInput in question:
        print(random_response)
    elif userInput == 'help':
        print('-------------------------------------------\nThis Program was created by Ethan Lee\nIf you need a list of Directories, Enter "directories".\n-------------------------------------------')
    elif userInput == 'directories':
        print("Enter the Program name to go to the program.\nPrograms:\n'Maps'\n'Google'\n'Safari'\n'Calculator'\n'Dictionary'\n'Calendar'\n'Contacts'\n'Chess'\n'Dashboard'\n'FaceTime'\n'GarageBand'\n'iBooks'\n'iMovie'\n'iTunes'\n'Kindle'\n'Launchpad'\n'Mail'\n'Messages'\n'Notes'\n'Photos'\n'Reminders'\n'Stickies'\n'TextEdit'\n'TextWrangler'\n'Xcode'")
    elif userInput in maps:
        webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/')
    elif userInput in google:
        webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')
elif userInput in mail:
    webbrowser.open('https://mail.google.com')
elif userInput in safari:
    os.system("open /Applications/Safari.app")
elif userInput in calc:
    os.system("open /Applications/Calculator.app")
elif userInput in dict:
    os.system("open /Applications/Dictionary.app")
elif userInput in cal:
    os.system("open /Applications/Calendar.app")
elif userInput in con:
    os.system("open /Applications/Contacts.app")
elif userInput in dash:
    os.system("open /Applications/Dashboard.app")
elif userInput in chess:
    os.system("open /Applications/Chess.app")
elif userInput in face:
    os.system("open /Applications/FaceTime.app")
elif userInput in band:
    os.system("open /Applications/GarageBand.app")
elif userInput in movie:
    os.system("open /Applications/iMovie.app")
elif userInput in ibooks:
    os.system("open /Applications/iBooks.app")
elif userInput in itunes:
    os.system("open /Applications/iTunes.app")
elif userInput in kindle:
    os.system("open /Applications/Kindle.app")
elif userInput in launch:
    os.system("open /Applications/Launchpad.app")
elif userInput in amail:
    os.system("open /Applications/Mail.app")
elif userInput in con:
    os.system("open /Applications/Contacts.app")
elif userInput in messages:
    os.system("open /Applications/Messages.app")
elif userInput in notes:
    os.system("open /Applications/Notes.app")
elif userInput in photos:
    os.system("open /Applications/Photos.app")
elif userInput in reminders:
    os.system("open /Applications/Reminders.app")
elif userInput in stickies:
    os.system("open /Applications/Stickies.app")
elif userInput in textwrangler:
    os.system("open /Applications/TextWrangler.app")
elif userInput in textedit:
    os.system("open /Applications/TextEdit.app")
elif userInput in xcode:
    os.system("open /Applications/Xcode.app")
elif userInput in emailing:
    emailh = raw_input('Your email: ')
    email = raw_input('Send to: ')
    subject = raw_input('Subject: ')
    body = raw_input('Body: ')
    yagmail.SMTP(emailh).send(email, subject, body)
    print('Email Sent.')
    file = open("email.txt", "a");
    file.write('Through\n')
    file.close()

else:
    print("I did not understand what you said\nEnter 'help' if you need help.\nEnter 'directories' if you need directories.")
```

(Actual process of opening and running commands)

Comment: A large part of you elif blocks is not correctly indented. This looks like a simple copy&paste error/not applying the code block correctly. Try pasting you whole code in, select it all and press the `{}` button (or presst Ctrl-K).

Answer (score 3):

You should learn about python dictionaries, see for example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

This way you can put all of your info in a nested dictionary which you can then loop over. This dictionary has as a key your old variable names and as values a dictionary with the keys `keywords`, `program`, and `command`.

This makes it also way easier to print all available commands.

For emailing, I would create a function. Here I would also use the `with..as` construct. You should also not use the name `file` as a variable name, because it is a built-in type. I would also write more than "Through", maybe the receiver of the email?

```
import random
import webbrowser
import os
import yagmail

COMMANDS = {
    "maps": {"keywords": ['maps', 'open google maps', 'open maps', 'please open google maps'],
             "program": webbrowser.open,
             "command": 'https://www.google.com/maps/'},
    "google": {"keywords": ['google', 'open google', 'please open google']
               "program": webbrowser.open,
               "command": 'https://www.google.com/'},
    "mail": {"keywords": ['mail', 'open mail', 'open google mail', 'please open google mail', 'gmail', 'open gmail', 'please open gmail'],
             "program": webbrowser.open,
             "command": 'https://mail.google.com'},
    "safari": {"keywords": ['safari', 'open safari', 'please open safari'],
               "program": os.system,
               "command": "open /Applications/Safari.app"},
    ...
    "emailing": {"keywords": ['send email', 'send'],
                 "program": emailing,
                 "command": ""}}

RESPONSES = ['Okay, How are you?', "I'm fine, How are you?"]
GREETINGS = ['hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!', 'hey']


def emailing(_):
    emailh = raw_input('Your email: ')
    email = raw_input('Send to: ')
    subject = raw_input('Subject: ')
    body = raw_input('Body: ')
    yagmail.SMTP(emailh).send(email, subject, body)
    print('Email Sent.')
    with open("email.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write('Sent email to {}\n'.format(email))


while True:
    userInput: raw_input(">>> ").lower()
    for say in (RESPONSES, GREETINGS):
        if userInput in say:
            print(random.choice(say))
            break
    if userInput == 'help':
        print('{0}\nThis Program was created by Ethan Lee\nIf you need a list of Directories, enter "directories".\n{0}'.format("-"*43))
    elif userInput == 'directories':
        print("Enter the Program name to go to the program. {}".format("\n".join(COMMANDS)))
    for choice in COMMANDS:
        if userInput in choice['keywords']:
            choice['program'](choice['command'])
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use python decorator. You can read about it [here](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html). Decorator can register function for the specified set of instructions and keep this information in the commands global storage.

I think it is better, because:

- command and corresponding function are situated at the same place of code;
- code is easy to read and extend;
- solution is universal whether it is print or send emails.

Here is an example of such an approach:

```
import random
import webbrowser
import os
import yagmail
#importing all module ^^


class action:
    """Class, that register action for commands
    with optional prefixes."""

    _all_commands = {}

    def __init__(self, commands, prefixes=None):
        """Save action parameters."""
        prefixes = list(prefixes or []) + ['']
        self.commands = ['{} {}'.format(p, c).strip() for p in prefixes for c in commands]

    def __call__(self, cmd_func):
        """Decorator, that register function
        for current action."""
        for cmd in self.commands:
            action._all_commands[cmd] = cmd_func

        return cmd_func

    @classmethod
    def call_command(cls, name, default=None):
        """Run action by command name. If not found - call default."""
        command = cls._all_commands.get(name, default)
        if callable(command):
            command()
        else:
            print('Command "%s" not found!' % name)


GREETINGS = ('hola', 'hello', 'hi', 'Hi', 'hey!','hey')


@action(GREETINGS)
def greet():
    print(random.choice(GREETINGS))


@action(['How are you?','How are you doing?'])
def question():
    print(random.choice(['Okay, How are you?',"I'm fine, How are you?"]))


@action(['help'])
def help():
    print('\n'.join((
        '-'*43,
        'This Program was created by Ethan Lee',
        'If you need a list of Directories, Enter "directories".',
        '-'*43
    )))


DIRS = ['Maps', 'Google', 'Safari']  # ... continue


@action(['dir', 'dirs', 'directories'])
def directories():
    print("Enter the Program name to go to the program.\n"
          "Programs: %s" % '\n'.join(DIRS))


@action(['maps', 'google maps'], prefixes=['open', 'please open'])
def maps():
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/')


@action(['google'], prefixes=['open', 'please open'])
def google():
    webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')


@action(['safari'], prefixes=['open', 'please open'])
def safari():
    os.system("open /Applications/Safari.app")


@action(['calc', 'calculator'], prefixes=['open', 'please open'])
def calc():
    os.system("open /Applications/Calculator.app")


# ....


@action(['send email', 'send'])
def emailing():
    emailh = input('Your email: ')
    email = input('Send to: ')
    subject = input('Subject: ')
    body = input('Body: ')
    yagmail.SMTP(emailh).send(email, subject, body)
    print('Email Sent.')
    file = open("email.txt", "a")
    file.write('Through\n')
    file.close()


def default():
    print("I did not understand what you said\n"
          "Enter 'help' if you need help.\n"
          "Enter 'directories' if you need directories.")

# ^^ Defining everything ^^

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        while True:
            user_input = input(">>> ").lower().strip()
            action.call_command(user_input, default)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Quit')
```